# Work of TeX infix operators

Tags: tex-core, fractions, mathjax

I check a work of TeX infix operators and have some questions. For example, it will be `\over`. The syntax is `{<subformula1> \over <subformula2>}`. It is ok, but i noticed that in this case `\left` and `\right` commands are treated as a begin/end group. So `{1 \left. 1 \over 2 \right. 2}` gives [image: render as].

This behaviour is similar for LaTeX, Mathjax and KaTeX. Can any other commands break a group?

The Big(g)(l,r) commands do not break a group, but let's check a `\middle` command. See how this expression will be rendered: `{1 \left. 1 \middle| 1 \over 2 \middle| 2 \right. 2}`, From classic LaTeX we get: [image: LaTeX render], Mathjax says "oops" (Math Processing Error), from KaTeX we get: [image: KaTeX render].

So the `\middle` command breaks a group in LaTeX, so I think canonically only `\left`, `\right`, or `\middle` commands are treated as group begin/end (of course also `{}`). Am I correct?

Comment: That's a problem of MathJax and KaTeX that apparently don't emulate well what TeX does. I don't think those two frameworks know about grouping. And, yes, in TeX `\left...\middle...\right` is two separate groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `\over` in LaTeX.

Anyway, you're correct in saying that `\left`, `\middle` and `\right` also form groups, besides choosing a suitable size for the delimiters.

It's a bit complicated, but not so much. Instead of using `\over`, I'll use a command that will be redefined in each part, to see that the redefinition is local and it's forgotten at the end of the group, witnessing the statement above.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}{x}
\newcommand{\redeftest}[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\test
\left(\frac{X}{Y} % for large size
         \test \redeftest{a} \test
\middle| \test \redeftest{b} \test
\middle| \test \redeftest{c} \test
\right)
\test
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A group started by `\left` can only be ended by `\right` or `\middle`. A group started with `\middle` can only be ended by `\right` or `\middle`. A trailing `\right` is mandatory. After TeX has scanned the whole `\left`–`\right` structure, it will also choose the appropriate size for the delimiters following `\left`, `\right` and all `\middle` commands that have appeared.

Groups can also be delimited by `{` and `}` (that can be aliased with `\bgroup` and `\egroup` when just grouping is involved), and by `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

“Mixing” these kinds of groups is illegal.

There is a big difference between `{...}` and `\begingroup...\endgroup` in math mode. The former construction builds a subformula, the latter doesn't. Also `\left`, `\middle` and `\right` build subformulas. A subformula is treated as a single object and spaces inside it are frozen (this is relevant in in-line formulas).

You can query the group type you're in with `\currentgrouptype`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}{x}
\newcommand{\redeftest}[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{#1}}

\newcommand{\gtype}{(\the\currentgrouptype)}

\begin{document}

\[
\test
\gtype
\left(\frac{X}{Y} % for large size
         \test \redeftest{a} \test \gtype
\middle| \test \redeftest{b} \test \gtype
\middle| \test \redeftest{c} \test \gtype
\right)
\test \gtype {\gtype} \begingroup\gtype\endgroup
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

- 15 means the current group is either inline or display math mode (here initiated by `[)
- 16 means the current group was initiated by `\left` or `\middle`
- 9 means “math group” (that is a subformula in `{...}`)
- 14 means a “semisimple group” delimited by `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.